# rails 4 has_many through join tables merge

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, merge, has-many-through

I have Projects:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :plans, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :items, through: :plans

 has_many :currents, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :items, through: :currents
end
```

I have Plans and same model, Currents (join tables):

```
class Plan < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :project
 belongs_to :item
 validates :quantity, presence: :true
end
```

My projects_helper.rb contains:

```
def filtered_currents
 tank = Current.where(:project_id => @project.id)
 currents = tank.group("item_id")
 @filtered_currents = currents.select("item_id, sum(quantity) as total_quantity")
end

def filtered_plans
 storage = Plan.where(:project_id => @project.id)
 plans = storage.group("item_id")
 @filtered_plans = plans.select("item_id, sum(quantity) as total_quantity")
end
```

This helpers works fine.

I can collect project plan's and current's in this url: /projects/2/projsum

### planned items:

**name      quantity**

concrete     20 t

tiles        52.1 m2

OSB          6 piece

### current items:

**name      quantity**

concrete     10 t

block         35 m2

OSB          4 piece

sand         22 m3

My aim is this results:

### combined items:

**name      quantity**

concrete     30 t

tiles        52.1 m2

OSB          10 piece

block         35 m2

sand         22 m3

How can I merge current items and planned items?

Comment: Your `Project` model has `has_many :items, through: :plans`  and `has_many :items, through: :currents`.How is that possible?

Comment: It is possible and works fine. Projects have got planned items and have got current items with quantity. I want to compare this two group.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is not clear. There are missing models, missing templates. I would encourage you to write a self-containing gist with the minimum amount of code which would show your problem [like Rails core recommends](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/guides/bug_report_templates/active_record_gem.rb) if it wasn't months since this was asked. Still, this showed up on Google, so why not answer?

Also, as @Pavan mentioned, having two associations with the same name is not good. I don't understand what you mean by "works fine" -- it's not fine. You can't access a project's planned items (`@project.items` always uses the second one).

Having said that, this is what I would do:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :plans, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :planned_items,
    through: :plans,
    source: :item

  has_many :currents, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :current_items,
    through: :currents,
    source: :item

  def items
    Item
      .joins(:plans, :currents)
      .where('plans.project_id = ? OR currents.project_id = ?', id, id)
      .uniq
  end
end
```